# DataFrame to multilevel columns dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having this initial dataframe :

```
print (df)
         Tenor  IV  RV
Ccy Pair              
EURUSD      1M   5   6
EURUSD      3M   5   6
EURUSD      6M   5   6
EURUSD      1Y   5   6
USDJPY      1M   5   6
USDJPY      3M   5   6
USDJPY      6M   5   6
USDJPY      1Y   5   6
GBPUSD      1M   5   6
GBPUSD      3M   5   6
GBPUSD      6M   5   6
GBPUSD      1Y   5   6
```

I would like to convert it to multi column one, such that the result is something like

```
          1M        3M        6M         1Y
CcyPair  RV | IV    RV | IV   RV | IV    RV | IV
 ----------------------------------------------
 EURUSD   5   6     5    6    5     6     5   6
 USDJPY   5   6     5    6    5     6     5   6
   ......
```

Is there a nice way to achieve this without creating manually single arrays from the original dataframe and convert it using multiIndex ?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Tenor', append=True).stack().unstack([1,2])
print (df)
Tenor    1M    3M    6M    1Y   
         IV RV IV RV IV RV IV RV
Ccy Pair                        
EURUSD    5  6  5  6  5  6  5  6
GBPUSD    5  6  5  6  5  6  5  6
USDJPY    5  6  5  6  5  6  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried it but it doesn't produce the right answer

Comment: @Crovish - Hard to test with data from picture :(

Comment: @Crovish - Answer was edited.